# omnet++ free( ): invalid pointer, error 134/139

Tags: c++, omnet++

I'm working on a project on Omnet++ anc C++ about simulating a protocol for p2p networks which is supposed to reconfigure them when a node exits. But sometimes the simulation crashes and exited and on the console I read: " *** glibc detected**  /opt/omnetpp-4.4/workspace/Progetto/Progetto: free(): invalid pointer: 0x09011e4c ** ".

So it seems that free( ) is the problem but the only deallocation that I do is
to delete the message after it has been handled. 
I've tried to remove

```
delete msg;
```

but the error keeps on happening. 
So, how could I fix this?
I don't know where that free() is called...

If someone wants to have a look at the code, it's here

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/jdrqrt93qazn4xd/ae-qVqgzEF

UPDATE:
I've just tried to launch my project (whose name is ./Progetto) with Valgrind using the following command that I've found in a tutorial:

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=yes --show-reachable=yes --num-callers=20 --track-    fds=yes ./Progetto > log.txt
```

I've copied the log in partebin and you can read it here:

```
http://pastebin.com/KBWLE2jV
```

I'm not able to understand that log, and why doesn't the project crash if launched with valgrind?
The only problem I see is that the project crashes when nodes send messages to themselves by scheduleAt( )...

Comment: Can you say the name of the file where `delete msg` is executed?

Comment: free() is called from operator delete, likely you've overwritten something or deleted msg twice.

Comment: Valgrind output or something similar would be useful (might even allow you to solve the problem yourself).

Comment: delete msg; is called only in file Node.cc at the end of the handler of messages.

Comment: I'm guilty to be not familiar with debugging tools...how does valgrind work?

Comment: @paulm: I use "delete msg;" only once at the end of the messages handler...I've tried to removed it so all the memory remains allocated but the problem always show up

Comment: Then you must be doing out of bounds writes, use Valgrind/AppVerifier

Comment: Is there any good tutorial to start with?

Comment: I don't know about everyone else, but I'm not grepping through your project to debug your code.  Boil it down to a small reproducible sample and post it here.

Answer (score 1):

A free but short code review :)

this struct:

```
struct secondNear {
    char near[8];
    char nearOfNear[8];
};
```

can be the source of many errors ... why not use `std::string` ?

then:

```
            secondNear* sn = new secondNear();
            strcpy(sn->near, received->getSender());
            strcpy(sn->nearOfNear, received->getNear());
            this->near2.push_back(*sn);
```

is again overcomplicated beside of the fact that it leaks memory. No need to create a new structure on the heap, just use stack.

And now your error: I think that you get a lot of `cModule` type ponters via `getSubModule()` and then you `free()` them instead of `delete`... they have the feeling of being classes (at least according to their usage) so possibly they are created via `new` and not `Xalloc`()

Comment: I'm not an expert of C++ (and less of Omnet++) and anytime I write some C++ code then I have the inclination to write it as a C code as much as possible. Anyway I guess I found the error yesterday. I simply was trying to get and erase the first element from an EMPTY list...which was supposed not to be empty. Valgrind didn't give me any help at all and I discovered it only thanks to one of my mates. Anyway thank you all. :)